# Write the Edittext to file

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

When I try to write the text to the file by this way, I can not found the "data" int my path.
*My phone does not have an SD card*

But I can find the file when I use the AVD.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //获取edittext中的内容
        String inputTest = edit.getText().toString();
        save(inputTest);//在销毁之前 调用save方法 
    }
    public void save(String inputText)
    {
        FileOutputStream outputStream =null;
        BufferedWriter writer=null;
        try {
            outputStream=openFileOutput("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            writer.write(inputText);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (writer!=null) {
                    writer.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to know the reason.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to my best to standardize my grammar.

Comment: Can you tell me how I solve the problem.